# Count characters in file/stream

Tags: .net, encoding, filestream

How can I get the length in *characters* (not bytes) of a stream / file? Let's assume the encoding for the file / stream is known (at runtime).

I'd rather not load the whole stream in memory, so I'm against using [`TextReader.ReadToEnd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readtoend.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the encoding is a fixed-width one (the same number of bytes for every character - e.g. ASCII but not UTF-8), you'll need to read the whole file - but it doesn't need to be in memory. For example:

```
public long CountCharacters(TextReader reader)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[8 * 1024]; 
    long total = 0;
    int charsRead;
    while ((charsRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        total += charsRead;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Used like this:

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText("file.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
{
    Console.WriteLine(CountCharacters(reader));
}
```

Note that this will count UTF-16 code units, which isn't quite the same as Unicode characters or displayable glyphs, but in *most* cases it will be good enough. (Consider cases such as combining characters and surrogate pairs.)

Comment: Wow, you answered faster than I could copy-paste my own stab at an implementation! ^:)^

Comment: Just one suggestion: the char count could concevably be larger than `int.MaxValue` so I'd suggest using `long total`... and a returned type of `long` instead of int

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu: True - will edit. (Are you likely to deal with files above 2GB, out of interest?)

Comment: Very unlikely - the files will be mirroring database CLOB fields; however, this is a library, so I can only guess how it will be used on the field.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have so far:

```
Stream stream = file.OpenRead("file.txt");
Encoding encoding = Encoding.Default; //or whatever

TextReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
var buf = new char[4096];
long total=0;
long crt;
while ((crt = reader.Read(buf, 0, 4096)) > 0)
{
   total += crt;
}

return total;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the encoding. If it is a fixed length encoding then divide the byte length by the size of the characters if it is a variable length encoding it is not knowable until the file has been processed.